# Variables in SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In the below query I noticed these named variables `wposts, wpostmeta` and was wondering how they work and what are they called (MySQL variables) so I can find out more information about using them in the MySQL docs.

Is it a shorthand so you don't have to type `$wpdb->postmeta` every time or is there more to this? Also, I don't understand the `SELECT wposts.*` there is no Wordpress table called wposts so what are you selecting from?

https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query

```
$querystr = "
        SELECT wposts.* 
        FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
        WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
        AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'custom-key' 
        AND wposts.post_type = 'page' 
        ORDER BY wpostmeta.meta_value DESC
 ";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are table aliases, and provide (generally) a short-hand way of referring to a table in a query. In your query the table whose name was `$wpdb->posts` is now referred to as `wposts`, and the table called `$wpdb->postmeta` is now referred to as `wpostmeta`. Note that once you have declared an alias, you **must** refer to the table using that alias, hence in your query you have references to `wposts.*`, `wpostmeta.meta_value` etc.

Note that you can also have column aliases, for example:

```
SELECT SUM(x) AS total FROM t1
```

Also note that the `AS` keyword I have shown in the column select above is optional and can be used for table and column aliases.

You can read more about aliases [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html).